# Who can explain the profiling result of tensorflow

Tags: profiling

I perform tensorflow profiling following the instruction at: https://medium.com/towards-data-science/howto-profile-tensorflow-1a49fb18073d

The following is the test code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline
import json

W=3000
H=4000

in_a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(W,H))
in_b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(W,H))

def test_sub(number):
    sess=tf.Session()
    options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
    run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
    many_runs_timeline=TimeLiner()

    out = tf.subtract(in_a,in_b)
    a=np.random.rand(W,H)
    b=np.random.rand(W,H)

    for i in range(number):
        feed_dict = {in_a:a,
                 in_b:b}
        t0=time.time()

        out_ = sess.run(out,feed_dict=feed_dict,options=options,run_metadata=run_metadata)

        fetched_timeline = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
        chrome_trace = fetched_timeline.generate_chrome_trace_format()
        many_runs_timeline.update_timeline(chrome_trace)

        t_=(time.time()-t0) * 1000
        print "index:",str(i), " total time:",str(t_)," ms"
    many_runs_timeline.save("timeline_merged_run_test.json")

class TimeLiner:
    _timeline_dict = None

    def update_timeline(self, chrome_trace):
        #convert crome trace to python dict
        chrome_trace_dict = json.loads(chrome_trace)

        # for first run store full trace
        if self._timeline_dict is None:
            self._timeline_dict = chrome_trace_dict

        # for other - update only time consumption, not definitions
        else:
            for event in chrome_trace_dict['traceEvents']:
                # events time consumption started with 'ts' prefix
                if 'ts' in event:
                    self._timeline_dict['traceEvents'].append(event)

    def save(self, f_name):     
        with open(f_name, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self._timeline_dict, f)

test_sub(20)
```

Running result of the code:
ndex: 0 total time: 338.145017624 ms
index: 1 total time: 137.024879456 ms
index: 2 total time: 132.538080215 ms
index: 3 total time: 133.152961731 ms
index: 4 total time: 132.885932922 ms
index: 5 total time: 135.06102562 ms
index: 6 total time: 136.723041534 ms
index: 7 total time: 137.926101685 ms
index: 8 total time: 133.605003357 ms
index: 9 total time: 133.143901825 ms
index: 10 total time: 136.317968369 ms
index: 11 total time: 137.830018997 ms
index: 12 total time: 135.458946228 ms
index: 13 total time: 132.793903351 ms
index: 14 total time: 144.603967667 ms
index: 15 total time: 134.593963623 ms
index: 16 total time: 135.535001755 ms
index: 17 total time: 133.697032928 ms
index: 18 total time: 136.134147644 ms
index: 19 total time: 133.810043335 ms

And the following image is the profiling result:[Profile Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx6a3.png)

**My question is:**
1. What is the difference between /gpu:0/stream:31(in the top part of the profiling result) and /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0(in the bottom part of the profiling result) and which is the execute time of tensorflow op? The author(in the link above) shows the /job:localhost part is the profile time of the job, but we can see from the profiling result that the /gpu:0/stream:31 costs the longer time.
2. The running result shows it takes about 140 ms to execute a session.run(), while the profiling result shows it takes only about 20 ms. And there is much time interval between two contiguous session.run(). What does the system do in the time interval?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your second question: there is a way how you can determine what is happening inside of that interval with help of Intel VTune Amplifier (the tool is not free, but there are free fully functional academic and trial versions). You can use a recipe from [this article](https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/articles/profiling-tensorflow-workloads-with-intel-vtune-amplifier) to import timeline data to Intel VTune Amplifier and analyze it there. You will need Frame Domain / Source Function grouping. Expand [No frame domain - Outside any frame] row and you will get the list of hotspots happening in the interval you are interested in.